# How to solve the error of psql: Argument list too long

Tags: bash, postgresql, arguments, psql

I am working on bash script with PostgreSQL. I have this line:

```
psql -h $PGHOST -p $PGPORT -U $PGUSER -d $PGDATABASE -c "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (${SQL%?}) AS query;" | grep '-' -A1 | grep -v '-' )
```

when I pass small query it works, however with some queries it give me this error.

```
/usr/bin/psql: Argument list too long
```

What this error means? how I increase the size of Argument list?

Comment: Congratulations you just hit ARG_MAX. look/search for `argument list too long` in this forum.

Comment: That limit effectively can not be changed. It's an operating system limit.

Comment: What they mean by Argument? Is it the relation names? or the resulted tuples?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is generally an OS hardcoded limit.

How are you setting the environment variable SQL?  Instead of setting SQL to a giant string, and then using `psql -c "..."`, could you have the generator of that giant string just stream it into `|psql` ?

Comment: I have not set the environment variable, I am working on a server which is owned by someone else.